# Error when reading from file in Lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to make my Lua program read from a file I have stored on my computer.  I am using this code:

```
function readFile(file)
    local file = io.open(file,"rb")
    local content = file:read("*all")
    file:close()
    return content
```

When I try running it, I get this error:

```
lua: io.lua:3: attempt to index local 'file' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    io.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
exit code: 1
```

I have found the solution to my original problem, however when I run the script it reports that the variable 'constant' is nil.

Input:

```
function readFile(filename)
    local file = io.open(filename,"rb")
    local content = file:read("*a")
    file:close()
    return content
end

readFile("test.txt")
print(content)
```

Output:

```
lua -e "io.stdout:setvbuf 'no'" "io.lua" 
nil
Exit code: 0
```

Comment: Did you actually pass a filename to the function?

Comment: third line should be `file:read("*a")` btw.

Comment: @greatwolf Actually this doesn't matter. Lua will accept any word beginning with `"a"`; see e.g. Lua 5.2.2 sources, file `liolib.c`, line 443: there is a `switch` using only the second char of the string. Of course this is an implementation detail and the user cannot rely on that, but it shouldn't be the source of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different local name than the function parameter.

```
 function readFile(filename)
 local file = io.open(filename, “rb”)
```

---

**UPDATE**

After your edit, there's still a problem:

```
readFile("test.txt")
print(content)
```

You are printing the global variable `content`, which is `nil`, what you want is:

```
print(readFile("test.txt"))
```

or:

```
local content = readFile("test.txt")
print(content)
```

Comment: Both of your answers work, however when returning it gives me the value "nil", any ideas on that one?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `io.open` in `assert`:

```
local file = assert( io.open(file,"rb") )
```

this will show you the error (if any) generated by the underlying OS.

Comment: Both of your answers work, however when returning it gives me the value "nil", any ideas on that one?